# how to show different payment options credit cards,debit cart, netbanking etc with ccavenue payment gateway in our website in magento

Tags: magento, ccavenue

I want to integrate ccavinue payment gateway in my website build in magento platform. integration is done in the way that after selecting the payment method, the customer is redirected to ccavinue site then he can see the different option like credit card/debit card, netbanking etc.

> **But I want customer can see the different options in our site and**
>   **after choosing one option he may be redirected to ccavinue site for**
>   **further processing.**

Can someone provide any solution.